# Java Byte Code ordering of this and parameters on the stack

Tags: java, parameters, jvm, stack, bytecode

In java bytecode why is the receiver is pushed onto the stack first followed by all the parameters? I seem to remember it being something to do with efficiency.

This is true for both method calls and setting fields.

Method Call

```
class X {

    int p(int a) {
        //Do something
    }
    int main() {
        int ret = p(1);
    }

}
```

Main method compiles to:

```
aload_0 // Load this onto the stack
iconst_1 // Load constant 1 onto the stack
invokevirtual <int p(int)> from class X
```

Setting a field:

```
class X {
    int x;
    int main() {
        x = 1;
    }

}
```

Main method compiles to:

```
aload_0 // Load this onto the stack
iconst_1 // Load constant 1 onto the stack
putfield <int x> from class X
```

Comment: Think I have figured it out but I can't answer as I don't have enough points!

Comment: This is one of those "idle curiosity" questions.  Interesting, but the answer is of no practical use ... unless you are contemplating designing a brand new bytecode instruction set.

Comment: your point being? Learning how a computer works is an "idle curiosity" question to most.

Comment: Well ... if it is idle curiousity, you should be doing your own research ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being pushed first has advantages in that

- The target method can use the denser "aload0" bytecode (smaller than
  if it were much later in the parameter list and had to use a
  parametric version of the aload bytecode.  Because "this" is often referenced in methods for both field and method access, it leads to a real code density improvement.
- One often does cascading method sends like "foo.bar().baz()".  When bar() returns,
  the future "this" for .baz() is magically already in the right place on the
  stack if you arrange things as was done in Java.

Comment: These answers are plausible, but in reality the bytecodes get compiled to native code, and neither of these advantages play out once that happens.

Comment: That's not correct for the second point on most RISC architectures like POWER where both parameters and return values are actually in registers.  Having them line up correctly (return -> arg 0) works very well and improves performance.  Also, on the first point, while 1 byte doesn't seem like much, the JVM often has to keep the bytecodes in memory (think class rewriting, etc.. from JVMTI) and adding up all those saved 1 bytes across thousands of classes adds up to non-trivial memory.

Comment: You are assuming that the virtual stack layout in the bytecode model resembles the physical stack layout used by the JIT compiled code.  Can you justify that assumption?  Re memory usage, a saving of tens or hundreds of thousands of bytes of bytecode >>is<< trivial ... on machines with gigabytes of physical memory.  Besides, once the bytecodes are JIT compiled they can be garbage collected.  (I'm not sure if they are ...)  And optimizing for the JVMTI case seems kind of pointless.

Comment: I can certainly justify it for the IBM JVM (J9) - I was one of the tech leads and wrote one of the JIT code generators and while the exact stack shape is different, the particular lining up of return value and parameter zero is very, very handy.  re: memory usage, I understand your thought, but this was a decision made 20 years ago in the context of small, embedded systems.  Things like that all add up, a byte here, a byte there.  Remember, I'm not justifying the decision for 2012, I'm justifying how it was made in the early 1990s.

Comment: re: bytecodes being JIT compiled then GCed, you could, you don't want to for several reasons:  1) the JIT may want the bytecodes for later to inline one method into another.  Or to recompile at higher opt levels (J9 and HotSpot both does this to various degrees) Without the source bytecodes, that's not easy. 2) optimization assumptions can change (new classes loaded that break JIT compile-time assumptions) and you need to recompile for correctness. 3)  classes aren't typically stored on the heap and are all one big entangled blob, so reclaiming partial classes is challenging in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking why it is pushed at all? In both cases you're accessing something that belongs to an instance of the class, so `this` has to be part of that process.

Are you asking why it is pushed first? Just Java convention. I guess it's convenient to always have `this` first regardless of the many things that could follow.

Comment: Asking the latter. The examples clearly show that I know why this is there. Thats the reason I thought of but it wouldn't let me post. It doesn't seem to be efficiency based as I'm sure I was told that it was. 

Hypothetically, even if the this was last you should still be able to resolve the position of it statically at compilation. I can't think of anything which would mean that you can't although I only know very basic JVM constructs.